# list-style-image is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create custom bullet points and it is not working.

This is my HTML.

```
<div id="services">
    <ul id="serviceText">
        <h2 id="serviceHeader"><strong>Services I Offer:</strong></h2>
        <li>Intros</li>
        <li>Transitions</li>
        <li>Lower Third Titles</li>
        <li>Web Page Design</li>
        <li>and more...</li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
ul#serviceText {
    list-style-image: url(images/checkmark.gif);
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: white;
}
```

[My site is located here xdtrammell.com/lol if it helps you to see all my code.](http://xdtrammell.com/lol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your selector to `ul#serviceText li`. Also keep in mind that you can't include `h2` element in `ul`. Is not valid html.

Comment: Thank You that was all that was wrong. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically I think you're trying to create custom bullets that are images, here is how I would do it.

The CSS

```
.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-li {
  background: url('../directory/your image here.jpg') no-repeat top left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

The key thing to note is the background image is in the top left, so take that into consideration when you adjust your padding. Padding is: Top, Right, Left, Bottom.

The HTML

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-item">lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You I will start to do it this way but as I said to Diodeus for right now I just needed them to get on the page for my project. Also the way you set it up wouldnt I use #list since you made them classes instead of ids.

Comment: Thanks, I've revised my answer :-) (its been a while)

Answer (score 1):

You're far better of using a CCS background for your list items than using `list-style-image`.  You get far greater control over the positioning of the graphic and the spacing of the text.

See: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Comment: Thanks I will look into that for the future, right now I just needed to get it there for my school project.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need the ../ before the image URL so it knows to go up a directory? In other words, does your image exist in the top level directory or in one of the next-levels? If it doesn't exist in the top level then it needs "../"

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path to image folder in URL like this(**../images/checkmark.gif**) and **"li"** tag element is enough as a selector.

```
li {list-style-image: url(../images/checkmark.gif);}
```

Answer (score 0):

my case was,
the bullet was hidden or invisible when `list-style: inside` was not set.